# How to order by two values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want a query that would order them by this kind of results :

- column = 1
- column = 2
- column = 1
- column = 2

and repeat

you see what i mean is, i want it to list results of two values of the same column value by value

EDIT :

ill make it more simple, column name has two values to verify something of 1 and 0

i want to use php to sort them down eachother but 1 follows it 0 and again 1 follows it 0, keeps going on this

table has other info that i want to extract but sorted by how its written aboce ^

Comment: Why requirement is so strange? Is it interview question?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my overly complicated code.

```
select bar
from (select bar, (@t := @t + 2) t
      from foo, (select @t := 0) dummy
      where bar = 1

      union all

      select bar, (@t2 := @t2 + 2) t
      from foo, (select @t2 := 1) dummy
      where bar = 2) temp
order by t;
```

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d5f0/19

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$sqlQuery1 = "SELECT distinct grade FROM loglists where
speciesNo='".$speciesData['speciesNo']."' and voyageNo='".$_REQUEST[voyageNo]."' order by
grade ASC, combinedgrade DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution for arrange order by multiple value.

```
select * from hotel where confId=13 group by hotelName ORDER BY CASE WHEN rating =  '5 Star'
THEN 1 
WHEN rating =  '4 Star'
THEN 2 
WHEN rating =  '3 Star'
THEN 3 
WHEN rating =  'BUDGET & EQUIVALENT HOTELS'
THEN 4 
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"select * from table order by field2,field3,field4";
```

the above sytnax is to order by multiple fields
use a foreach statement and check if its column1 and column 2 and display them

Comment: That's obviously not what he asks.